# Ember, generating URL `url-to`?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars, ember.js-2

I would like to generate a URL to a resource and show it to the User. I found the [link-to](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/links/) but I don't want the whole `<a>` element but only the URL.

Something like:

```
{{#url-to 'photos.show' photo}}
```

Comment: what you can do is create a handlebars helper to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what Emberjs version you are using but in any case this may work for you. I haven't try my self but probably will help you.

```
{{#url-to 'photos.show' photo}}

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('url-to', function() {
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'].apply(this, args);
});
```

Check this [tutorial](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2014/01/11/custome-link-to/) which goes more in details. Also you can search for how to create blocs helpers in emebrjs.

Answer (score 0):

there is addon which adds such helper `{{href-to}}` have a look https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to